# unable to append content to an array

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This might seems complex but I guess it's actually pretty simple one.

I am trying to pass my date in Firebase to tableviewCell in my VC

Here's my database structure

```
"2016-10-24 MON" : {
"types" : {
  "LUNCH" : {
    "TypeA" : "2",  //the amount
    "TypeB" : "1",
    "TypeC" : "1"
  },
  "DINNER" : {
    "TypeA" : "1",
    "TypeB" : "2",
    "TypeC" : "3"
  }
}
}
"2016-10-26 WED" : {
"types" : {
  "LUNCH" : {
    "TypeA" : "0",
    "TypeB" : "2",
    "TypeC" : "3"
  },
  "DINNER" : {
    "TypeA" : "2",
    "TypeB" : "2"
  }
}
```

and this is my code

```
class orderDetail: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

var theARRAY : [(DATES: String, TimeDeliv: String, AmountA:String, AmountB: String, AmountC: String)] = []


 override func viewDidLoad() {

    theREF.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in 
//theREF is my Firebase Reference



        if let Date = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
            for each in Date {

                let orderdate = each.0 as! String

                theREF.child(orderdate).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

                    if snapshot.hasChild("LUNCH") {

                        theREF.child(orderdate).child("LUNCH").observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in

                     if let snapDict = snapshot.value as? Dictionary <String, AnyObject> {

                                let Num1 = snapDict["TypeA"] as? String
                                let Num2 = snapDict["TypeB"] as? String
                                let Num3 = snapDict["typeC"] as? String


                                self.theARRAY.append((DATES: "\(orderdate)", TimeDeliv:"LUNCH", AmountA:"TypeA \(Num1)", AmountB:"TypeB \(Num2)", AmountC :"TypeC \(Num3)"))

                            }

  })


                        print("LUNCH works \(snapshot)")
                    } else {
                        print ("NONE")
                    }
                })

            }
        }
    }
    )



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return theARRAY.count
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DetailCell") as! detailCell!


    cell?.detailMealTypeA.text = theARRAY.AmountA
    cell?.detailMealtypeB.text = theARRAY.AmountB
    cell?.detailMealtypeC.text = theARRAY.AmountC
    // these are from UItableViewCell file


    return cell!
}
```

What I am trying to do is I want to append details in Database to `theARRAY` and then shoe them in tableViewCell but I keep getting `0` in `numberOfRowsInSection` and `nil` in `cellForRowAt` function.

I think it's because I call `theARRAY.append` at wrong line.

Can someone please help me out here?

Please excuse my nasty code by the way.

Comment: Is your `snapshot` printed? If yes, try printing the size of the array right after appending your contents. If the size is increasing, then your append works and you simply have to reload your `tableview` since your array now does contain the respective data. Add `self.tableView.reloadData()` right after your for loop

Comment: @EmilDavid , This is just what I need!! What a stupid mistake :( 
Thanks, you saved my ass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `viewDidLoad` is called, your tableview is configured right away without waiting for your Firebase call's completion.

Once you are done retrieving your data, you need to reflect these changes back and update your UI thread. Add the following line outside the for loop.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async
{
  self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```